# Inserting spaces before the word while adding lines using sed

Tags: sed

My file content-

```
abc
def
```

I want to add two lines after abc with spaces before it

My final file content should be -

```
abc
    123
def
```

I am using the below command, but not working for me, plz help me

```
sudo sed -i "/abc/a\\\123" file.txt
```

Note - There is no space between lines, I just want to put some spaces before the new line (i.e. before the line 123)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -i '/abc/a\    123' file
```

Ex:

```
$ sed '/abc/a\    123' file
abc
    123
def
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is `awk` solution ,if you are open for awk.

Sample input:

```
cat infile
abc
def
```

**Explanation:**

Check for pattern `abc` if found, update the current line with current line followed by newline followed by `123`. And `1` invokes `awk`'s default action of printing.

note : Newline is printed using `awk`'s inbuilt variable called `ORS` ,which is default set to newline.

```
awk '/abc/ {$0=$0 ORS "    123" }1' infile
abc
    123
def
```

To make changes in orignal file:

```
awk '/abc/ {$0=$0 ORS "    123" }1' infile >infile.tmp && mv infile.tmp infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk for clarity, portability, etc.:

```
awk '{print} /abc/{print "    123"}' file
```